# Unable to start program 'DTS' OLE has sent a request and is waiting for a reply

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc

I'm getting this error when trying to view my data flow tab in Visual Studio.  FWIW, this is a package that I've copied from a different server and am trying to get it to execute on the new server.  I've changed the definition of the SQL Server related connection manager, but I think that this problem is related to the portion of the data flow which pertains to the ODBC data source, which is selecting data from a PostgreSQL database.  A prior step, which truncates the SQL Server target tables executes without problem.

I have validated that the (32 bit) ODBC connection seems to work.  It passes the connection test, anyway.

FWIW, I'm new to the SQLServer world.  I've spent a bit of time building this package on a Virtual Server, but am trying to move it to a larger production server.  Point being, I don't necessarily know all the details of the environment.

ps--All this is on SQL Server BI 2012 on Windows 2012 server (the newest version, whatever it's called).

UPDATE:  Here is the full text (or more full, anyway) of the error:

OLE has sent a request and is waiting for a reply.
 (Microsoft Visual Studio Debugger)

---

Program Location:

at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(Int32 errorCode)
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.Project.DataTransformationsPackageDebugger.LaunchVsDebugger(IVsDebugger iVsDebugger, DataTransformationsProjectConfigurationOptions options)

Comment: Have you checked that the SQLAgent is running on the new server? I don't know that its not running would cause this problem, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: Thank you for that help.  I double-checked as saw that SQLAgent is indeed running.

Comment: Is the subject, unable to start program DTS OLE, the actual error message? When running it from Visual Studio/SSDT-BI, copy the details of the Output window (Ctrl-Alt-O or View, Output) and edit your existing question so we can get an idea of what your package is doing, how it's failing. Finally, what is the package supposed to do? Something with pulling data out of PostgreSQL

Comment: If you create a brand new package with that connection, do you still have the issue?

Comment: The server you copied the package from, was it also a SQL Server 2012 instance?